# How to calculate the similarity/distance between multiple measures for a single individual

Tags: correlation, distance, distance-functions

I have what may be a relatively simple query, but I'm unsure of the best way to do it. I would like to calculate the similarity between multiple measures for a single individual. I have a data matrix like this:

```
ID    Var1     Var2     Var3    Var4 .... Var10
1     6        1        7       3         4
2     3        2        8       1         5 
3     4        2        7       2         4
4     5        1        9       1         4
....
```

For each individual I would like a measure of how closely Variables 1-10 are related - almost like a correlation co-efficient, but for a single row of data. Ideally this measure should also take into account the *direction* of the scores (the data is a scale where 1 is bad and 10 is good). For this reason simply using the standard deviation would not work, as individuals who both do very poorly on everything and very well on everything would both have a low SD (as all their scores would be very similar).

For those of you familiar with `qgraph` or `igraph` in R, I am hoping to derive a similiar individual-level 'connectness' measure (i.e. how closely the measures are related for one individual) which takes into account how good or poorly they are doing across those measures.

Apologies if this replicates a previous post but I have not quite found one which addresses this question. I feel there should be a relatively intuitive way to do it; any suggestions or advice would be very welcome, thank you!